# decimal number conversion without arithmetic operations

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment and need some help with the output. I need to convert a decimal integer to a binary integer WITHOUT built in java functions and any arithmetic. I am using bit-wise operations to read the right most bit, then shift to the right. The issue I'm having is that my output is backwards and I cannot figure out how to flip it.  For example, if I use 66, I expect the output would be 1000010.  However, my program's output is 0100001.
Thanks for the help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project2Exercise3 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a posotive integer between 1 and 2^32-1");
      String stringNumber = input.nextLine();
      long decimalNumber = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(stringNumber);

     while(decimalNumber > 0) {
       long binaryNumber = (decimalNumber & 1);
       System.out.print(binaryNumber);
       decimalNumber = (decimalNumber >> 1);
     } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Something like this can help ...declare binaryNumber outside of while loop and also declare int X = 1, , then binaryNumber = binaryNumber + ((decimalNumber&1)*X) inside the loop make X = X*10,  X = 1, 10, 100, 1000....

Answer (score 1):

with `(decimalNumber & 1)` you will get the right most bit so you are printing it from the right hence the issue

You can collect your bits and reverse it to print it at the end.

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  StringBuffer nums = new StringBuffer();
  System.out.println("Enter a posotive integer between 1 and 2^32-1");
  String stringNumber = input.nextLine();
  long decimalNumber = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(stringNumber);
  while(decimalNumber > 0) {
    // store the bits
    nums.append(String.valueOf(decimalNumber & 1));
    decimalNumber = (decimalNumber >> 1);
  } 
  // reverse and convert it into string
  System.out.print(nums.reverse().toString());
```

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/VXBZr6)

Comment: StringBuffer, haven't seen that dinosaur for very long time :)

Comment: kinda old school maybe, should have used builder but can't help it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function to print your number:

```
void printBinary(long n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        printBinary(n >> 1);
    }
    System.out.print(n & 1);
}
```

Because the printing happens as the recursion unwinds it will automatically print the digits in the required order.

The only caveat with the code as written is that it will always print a leading zero.